# How to create functions that actually store information for later sessions? (elisp)

Tags: list, emacs, save, elisp

I want to give the user the option to add things to a list, which then gets saved for further sessions. How to do this in elisp?

```
(setq smart-pair-alist
      '(("(" . ")")             ; key 0
        ("[" . "]")             ; key 1
        ("{" . "}")             ; key 2
        ("\"" . "\"")           ; key 3
        ))

(defun smart-pair-adder (open close &optional mode)
  (add-to-list 'smart-pair-alist `(,open . ,close)  t)
  )

(smart-pair-adder "a" "b")
```

smart-pair-alist evaluates to:

`(("(" . ")") ("[" . "]") ("{" . "}") ("\"" . "\"") ("a" . "b"))`

Really nice that it adds, but how to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, for thing like this, saving the content of the variable and loading it in future sessions is not the best way to do things. (Things that *do* fall into this category are things like the minibuffer command history, search history etc.)

Instead, a user typically have an *init file*, in which function calls like the following can be placed:

```
(smart-pair-adder "a" "b")
```

This is advantageous from a number of reasons:

- It is future safe, in case the package used change the content or format of the variable
- It is more robust. In case a variable, somehow, would get the wrong value, that value would be retained forever if it was saved
- It is easier to maintain (as in writing comments) a hand-maintained file rather than an automatically generated save file
- Save files plays badly with *custom*, a system designed for interactive configuration of Emacs variables. This system has it's own way of storing and restoring variables.

Comment: After reconsidering I guess I agree with you!

Answer (score 1):

If the user is using `savehist-mode` to save the minibuffer history, you can use `savehist-additional-variables` to presist the value of an arbitrary variable:

```
(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'smart-pair-alist)
```